Symbolic center of mass of the solution of linear inequalities
Given m linear equations over n + m variables {v1, ..., vn, c1, ..., cm}, how can I find the center of mass (CoM) of the part of n-dimensional hyperspace defined by vi >=0 and the equations? The CoM in general will be an expression with the cj variables still free.
Assume the equations are such that this part is always finite.
My main confusion is coming from the free cj variables, otherwise I could solve inequalities iteratively (one by one), find pairwise intersections between the hyperplanes, and enumerate all the small hyper-polyhedra (maybe simplices), combining their CoMs at the end. But free cj introduce a lot of potential alternatives in the topology of the surface of the subspace I am interested in. I can solve for all alternatives, and then try and simplify the piecewise-linear expression. Sounds like a lot of grunt-work, I suspect I am missing some higher-level tools already available.
A trivial example:
from sympy import symbols, linsolve, solve

v = symbols("v:2")
c = symbols("c:1")
eqs = [v[0] + v[1] - c[0]] # constrain the sum

subs, = linsolve(eqs, v)
ineqs = [b >= 0 for b in subs] # all v nonnegative
solve(ineqs, v[1]) #.as_set() not implemented for multivariate
# Essentially, v1 is in [0, c0].
# Using subs, v0 is in [0, c0] as well; so CoM = (c0/2, c0/2).

A slightly more complicated example, demonstrating how branching/nonlinearity of max drastically complicates CoM:
from sympy import symbols, linsolve, solve

v = symbols("v:3")
c = symbols("c:2")
eqs = [v[0] + v[1] + v[2] - c[0], v[1] + 2 * v[2] - c[1]]

subs, = linsolve(eqs, v)
ineqs = [b >= 0 for b in subs] # all v nonnegative
print(ineqs)
solve(ineqs, v[2])
# Essentially, v2 is in [max(0, c1 - c0), c1/2].
# Using subs, v1 is in [0, c1 - 2 * max(0, c1 - c0)]
# v0 is quite complicated, as is CoM.

Potential high-level solution: if there was a way to integrate linear expressions over the solution of a set of linear inequalities, then each coordinate of the CoM is integrate(s[i], solve(ineqs, v)) / integrate(1, solve(ineqs, v)), where s[i] is a substitution for v[i] implied by equations.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible code example?

Added two examples.

"J. Lawrence. Polytope volume computation. Mathematics of Computation, 57:259–271, 1991" seems relevant: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/IR/nistir89-4123.pdf
